# Error While trying to connect to DB2 SAMPLE database for the First TIme

Tags: database, db2

I want to install DB2 UDW in my machine for learning purpose but I am having a hard time configuring the local instance. Any help would be highly appreciated.

I installed DB2 express edition -c . I have selected all the default choices. I am trying to connect using IBM data Studio 4.1,  In the "DB2 first Steps"  GUI I have chosen to create SAMPLE Database. I am getting the below error

**Creating database "SAMPLE" on path "C:"...
  Existing "SAMPLE" database found...
    The "-force" option was not specified...
  Attempt to create the database "SAMPLE" failed
  'db2sampl' processing complete.**

I tried connecting from Data Studio using the following options

Database- SAMPLE
Port- 50000
host - localhost

Error I am getting

**Explanation**:
An attempt was made to access a database that was not found, has not been started, or does not support transactions.
**User response:**
Ensure that the specified database name exists in the system database directory. If the database name does not exist in the system database directory, either the database does not exist or the database name has not been cataloged. If needed, issue a db2start command and then resubmit the current command.
SQL4499N A fatal error occurred that resulted in a disconnect from the data source.
SQLSTATE: 08004

Problem is I am having zero knowledge in DB2.   If I need to run db2start command from where I should run this?  Please help

Answer (score 0):

Probably the instance is not started.

Once you have installed DB2, you need to have an started instance in order to use any database. The instance could be created at the same time of the installation. You can verify which instances exist in your computer by issuing:

```
/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/instance/db2ilist
```

The output should give you a set of users, where an instance has been configured.
You can change to that user and start the instance. For example if the user is db2inst1

```
su - db2inst1
db2start
```

Once the instance is started, you can now create a database and then connect to it.

Comment: Thanks it worked!!  but I have another problem now. after creating the connection using db2admin user which gets created during installation while issuing SELECT query I am getting the below error ,can you please advise?
The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.  Authorization ID: "DB2ADMIN".  Operation: "SELECT". Object: "ASFAKUL.EMPLOYEE".. SQLCODE=-551, SQLSTATE=42501, DRIVER=3.67.28

Comment: Create another question for this error. It is just to keep the question clear in StackOverFlow. Describe the error, and I will try to help you.

Comment: I somehow resolved the problem. I was logged in using DB2 admin user which doesn't have select privilege on tables belonging to user asfakul. I logged in using user asfakul and voila it's done

Comment: Exactly, something to do with secadm and data access.